# Which Exception should I throw (trying to save read-only file)

Tags: c#, exception

I can instantiate some class with read-only parameter (you can read from specified file).

Also I have a "Save" method which saves all changes to currently opened files. When some1 will call Save in read-only mode, it should throw an exception.

What Exception should I use? (I think of InvalidOperationException).

Comment: you can make your own exception

Comment: This is a very subjective question. InvalidOperationException seems at least as good as anything else though, so yes, use that.

Comment: PrivilegeNotHeldException сould also fit your purpose. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.privilegenotheldexception.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InvalidOperationException is the exception you can throw!!

here is the link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx

Answer (score 5):

[`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) indeed sounds applicable:

> The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the
>   object's current state.

Since the object's state is "read-only" the exception fits the situation.

Note that `NotSupportedException` might also be good: in the BCL, trying to [write to a read-only stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.write.aspx) or [add to a read-only collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63ywd54z.aspx) both result in [`NotSupportedException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception.aspx):

> The exception that is thrown when an invoked method is not supported,
>   or when there is an attempt to read, seek, or write to a stream that
>   does not support the invoked functionality.

Comment: NotSupportedException for an intrinsically read only type seems fine. In the case of the OP, the "read-onliness" is due to the particular state of the object, at that moment in time - it is not intrinsic to the type. So I would not use NotSupportedException in this case.

Comment: @MikeGoodwin: I agree, but note that a `FileStream` is also not intrinsically read-only (unless you count the options passed when the file was opened as intrinsic properties, which to me they are not).

Comment: @MikeGoodwin, the NotSupportedException for an intrinsically read only object is never fine as it breaks the Liskov substitution principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). The read only list in the .NET BCL is a code smell class as it does this.

Comment: @David Arno: Good point. I suppose what I should say, it that it is even less OK for an object that is sometimes read only and sometimes not :o)

Comment: From documentation: "For scenarios where it is sometimes possible for the object to perform the requested operation, and the object state determines whether the operation can be performed, see InvalidOperationException."

Comment: @MikeGoodwin, that makes sense. Nicely put :)